# sea otter pun - please help

Tags: meaning, pun

On 10 December 2019, @MontereyAq tweeted the following sea otter pun:
"sea otters imply the existence of land better-nots".
The twitter account of the Monterey Bay Aquarium is famous for its way-out puns, but normally I get them. This one I don't understand at all. Can someone here enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a very good pun. The opposite of "sea" is "land". "otter" in US is pronounced almost the same as "[oughta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UEWbTxmG9o)" ... "ought to", and the opposite of "ought to" is "better not".

Comment: I find it hard to rate the quality of puns, since a lot of them are intentionally silly. But thanks for enlightening me.